# Get firebase function url from admin SDK programatically

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Is there a way to get the Firebase Function url from the Admin SDK for nodejs?

In prod it will look like: `https://REGION-PROJECT.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME`

And when serving locally: `http://localhost:PORT/PROJECT/REGION/FUNCTION_NAME`

Is it possible to get this value in nodejs programmatically? E.g. from admin or configuration settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK doesn't expose any APIs that deal with Cloud Functions.  From what you've shared, it sounds like you have everything you need to build the URL yourself, which is the right way to go.

If you really must use another piece of software, you'll have to dive very deep into the inner workings of the Firebase CLI and figure out how to reuse its code.  You'll probably have to look in two places - one for the emulator, and another for deployment.  I suspect this is almost certainly not going to be worth your time, since building the strings yourself is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Hey Doug, I get your point and I guess given you past relation with Firebase sounds the only way. It would have been perfect if there was an exposed setting to know that info without going through the manual hassle...

Comment: Feel free to send any feature requests to Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't say exactly what you want to accomplish, I'll just guess that you want your app to be aware of when you're in development vs. production mode.

What I did was to simply write in some checks in my front- and back-end code.  For instance, in the browser/web code:

```
if (window.location.href.toString().includes('localhost:5000')) {
// exhibit desired behavior for emulator
} else {
// exhibit desired behavior for production
}
```

Depending on how you're calling your node/backend functions, you could pass along the execution context (emulated or production), and use that in the back, too.

It's not perfect, but it's actually streamlined development for me quite a bit.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for you effort but what you wrote is about web api and what I am looking is the (backend) admin SDK

Comment: no problem, I was just saying that the way I talked to my back end about whether an emulator was running was via my front end.  if you find a better solution, I'd love to see an answer posted back here